# Homework to display a square and calculate tips

Tags: c++, homework, calculator, ascii-art

Here's a simple school assignment I did:

> Problem 1: Write a program that asks the user for a positive integer
>   no greater than 15. The program should then display a square on the
>   screen using the character “X”. The number entered by the user will be
>   the length of the side of the square. For example, if the user enters
>   5, the program should display the following:
>
> ```
> XXXXX 
> XXXXX 
> XXXXX 
> XXXXX 
> XXXXX
> ```
>
> Problem 2: Imagine that you and a number of friends go to a restaurant
>   and when you ask for the bill you want to split the amount and the tip
>   between all. Write a function
>
> ```
> double CalculateAmountPerPerson(double TotalBill, double TipPercentage, int NumFriends)
> ```
>
> that takes the total bill amount, tip percentage (e.g., 15.0 for a 15%
>   tip), and the number of friends as inputs and returns the total bill
>   amount as its output.
>
> Write a main function that asks the user for the total amount of the
>   bill and the size of his/her party (i.e., number of friends) and
>   prints out the total amount that each person should pay for tip
>   percentages of 10%, 12.5%, 15%, 17.5%, 20%, 22.5%, 25%, 27.5%, and
>   30%. Your main function should use a loop and invoke the
>   CalculateAmountPerPerson function at each iteration.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void menuPrompt();
short getMenuSelection();
void program1();
void squareLengthPrompt();
void displaySquare(int, char);
void program2();
void billPrompt();
void numPeoplePrompt();
double CalculateAmountPerPerson(double, double, int);
const short PROGRAM_1 = 1;
const short PROGRAM_2 = 2;
const short EXIT = 0;

int main(int argc, char *arv[]) {
    while(true) {
        char menu = getMenuSelection();
        switch (menu) {
            case EXIT:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            case PROGRAM_1:
                program1();
                break;
            case PROGRAM_2:
                program2();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "That program doesn\'t exist." << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void menuPrompt() {
    std::cout
        << "Menu:\n"
        << "\t1. Program 1\n"
        << "\t2. Program 2\n"
        << "\t0. Exit\n"
        << "Select your program: "
    << std::flush;
}
short getMenuSelection() {
    short selection = 0;
    while (selection != PROGRAM_1 && selection != PROGRAM_2) {
        menuPrompt();
        std::cin >> selection;
    }
    return selection;
}
void program1(){
    const char SQUARE_CHARATER = 'X';
    short squareLength = 0;
    while (squareLength > 15 || squareLength < 1) {
        squareLengthPrompt();
        std::cin >> squareLength;
    }
    displaySquare(squareLength,SQUARE_CHARATER);
}
void squareLengthPrompt() {
    std::cout
        << "Enter the length of the side of the square (Between 1 and 15): "
        << std::flush;
}
void displaySquare(int side, char character) {
    for(int i = 0; i < side ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < side; ++j) {
            std::cout << character;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
void program2() {
    const float TIP_PERCENTAGES[] = {.10, .125, .15, .175, .20, .225, .25, .275, .30};
    double totalBill = 0;
    int totalPeople = 0;
    double amountPerPerson;
    while (totalBill <= 0) {
        billPrompt();
        std::cin >> totalBill;
    }
    while (totalPeople <= 0) {
        numPeoplePrompt();
        std::cin >> totalPeople;
    }
    for(auto tipPercent: TIP_PERCENTAGES){
        amountPerPerson = CalculateAmountPerPerson(totalBill,tipPercent, totalPeople);
        std::cout << "With the tip percentage of " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
            << tipPercent*100 << "%, each person pays " << amountPerPerson
            << " from a $" << totalBill << " bill. " << std::endl;
    }
}
double CalculateAmountPerPerson(double TotalBill, double TipPercentage, int
                                NumFriends) {
    return (TotalBill*(1+TipPercentage))/NumFriends;
}
void billPrompt() {
    std::cout
        << "Enter the total of your bill (must be greater than 0): "
        << std::flush;
}
void numPeoplePrompt() {
    std::cout
        << "Enter the number people that are splitting the bill (must be greater than 0): "
        << std::flush;
}
```

I primarily just want to know if the code is self documenting and if I should include comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is not self-documenting, because the problem description is non-trivial and involves what you'd call "business logic". That is, you're not trying to perform some technical operation (like a cache, or a data structure, or a parser), but you're following rules defined by someone else. Each of those rules has to be programmed in, of course, but without describing WHY they have been put in, you'll always need the problem description along with the code to make sense of the code.

Imagine you had posted your question without the problem description. Would we have been able to guess what the goal of your assignment was?

Personally, yes, I think so. This is because if I were to run your program, it asks clear questions and prints a clear result. It does require a non-trivial time investment, though.

You get

> "Enter the length of the side of the square (Between 1 and 15): "

As output on the screen, you enter a number, you get a square. Program 1 will print a square.

And seeing something like

```
for(auto tipPercent: TIP_PERCENTAGES){
    amountPerPerson = CalculateAmountPerPerson(totalBill,tipPercent, totalPeople);
    std::cout << "With the tip percentage of " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
        << tipPercent*100 << "%, each person pays " << amountPerPerson
        << " from a $" << totalBill << " bill. " << std::endl;
}
```

In the code tells me that program 2 is for splitting up a bill.

In that sense, the code is self documenting. We don't need the problem description. We can see what the code does, because we can execute it.

What comments are for, then, are not for explaining what the code does. That understanding can already be achieved by, well, reading and executing the code.

Comments have 2 main uses, in my opinion: First, to explain the why of the code (why does the code do what it does). Second, to help speed along the understanding the code. Basically, rather than making me read and execute the entire program, spending lots of time, you simply put the purpose of a part of code in a comment, and I can read what the code does via condensed comments. Like reading a recipe instead of watching someone actually cook something.

The act of making code self-documenting, then, is to put these comments into active code. Putting the why into code is hard; the only places you can possibly do this is in error messages - "number of people must be greater than 0, cannot split bill between 0 or negative people" - stuff like that explains why there is a `totalPeople <= 0` check. I don't recommend going out of your way to do that; comments are for the programmer and output is for the user.

Putting the how comments into code is a lot easier. You can use function names for this.

Compare:

```
    amountPerPerson = CalculateAmountPerPerson(totalBill,tipPercent, totalPeople);
```

and

```
    s = calc(sum, pct, num);
```

One is clear to understand, the other could mean anything. Yet it can even make sense after we give it a comment...

```
    double s; //share per person
    s = calc(sum, pct, num); //calculate share per person using sum costs, tip percentage and number of people
```

So you've, in essence, already done this "importing of comments".

---

There are still a few improvements to be made.

For instance...

```
void program2() {
    const float TIP_PERCENTAGES[] = {.10, .125, .15, .175, .20, .225, .25, .275, .30};
    double totalBill = 0;
    int totalPeople = 0;
    double amountPerPerson;
    while (totalBill <= 0) {
        billPrompt();
        std::cin >> totalBill;
    }
    while (totalPeople <= 0) {
        numPeoplePrompt();
        std::cin >> totalPeople;
    }
    for(auto tipPercent: TIP_PERCENTAGES){
        amountPerPerson = CalculateAmountPerPerson(totalBill,tipPercent, totalPeople);
        std::cout << "With the tip percentage of " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
            << tipPercent*100 << "%, each person pays " << amountPerPerson
            << " from a $" << totalBill << " bill. " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`program2` as a whole is hard to understand. You have to carefully read what it does to see what it does. Had you instead renamed the function to `runBillSplitterProgram`, we'd have gotten a hint of the meaning already.

Internally, you have tried splitting certain sections up, but you're only done this for the long strings.

We can do slightly better by not separating based on code length, but on functionality:

```
//in runBillSplitterProgram
double amountPerPerson;
double totalBill = askForTotalBill();
int totalPeople = askForTotalPeople();

//as separate functions        
double askUserForTotalBill() {
    double totalBill = 0;
    while (totalBill <= 0) {
        std::cout
            << "Enter the total of your bill (must be greater than 0): "
            << std::flush;
        std::cin >> totalBill;
    }
    return totalBill;
}

int askUserForTotalPeople() {
    int totalPeople = 0;
    while (totalPeople <= 0) {
        std::cout
            << "Enter the number people that are splitting the bill (must be greater than 0): "
            << std::flush;
        std::cin >> totalPeople;
    }
    return totalPeople;
}
```

It's a shame one is a double and the other is an integer, or you'd been able to merge both into some sort of `askUserForValue` function, keeping `billPrompt` as a function which calls `askUserForValue` with a lengthy string.

---

Technical commentary:

```
while (!(1 <= squareLength && squareLength <= 15))
```

reads better as a range check.

---

Overall, you've done a pretty good job. You should add a program header describing the exercise.

Comment: "It's a shame one is a double and the other is an integer, or you'd been able to merge both" you can merge them with generics i think.

Comment: @Caridorc That would be a great answer; but it's not really in scope of my answer as I treat the asker as a bit of a beginner - handing in a solution with generics might be a bit over the top for a task such as this

Comment: Well, I really try to avoid code cuplication even if the cost in complexity is big. Repeated code means that (the subset of) the language you are using is not abstract enough.

Comment: And generics are really not that hard (it is like formal parameters for types instead of values (first class types))

Comment: @Caridorc I'm suggesting that you post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I would but I cannot access my computer and therefore cannot test in this period of the year (from mobile) so I do not feel confident enough to answer :)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the thorough feedback. This is the first time I've ever received any code review. "The code is not self-documenting, because the problem description is non-trivial and involves what you'd call "business logic". That is, you're not trying to perform some technical operation (like a cache, or a data structure, or a parser), but you're following rules defined by someone else."  I'm having a really hard time understanding those two sentences. Could clarify a little bit?

Comment: @HarrisonTran Using terminology from another branch - woodworking - imagine you had to make a dovetail joint - describing a dovetail joint wouldn't be needed between experienced woodworkers, because both of them would know what a dovetail joint would look like. Documentation would be like "the sides of the box are connected via a dovetail joint" and that'd be it. When you need to create something which isn't a clear concept, then you HAVE to describe it. You can't just give it a name and expect people to understand. Perhaps it was poorly phrased of me.

Comment: @Pimgd Ah, I think I understand. Basically given the context of the expected person to read the source code/documentation, I should document things that most of the audience of the source code wouldn't naturally know. In my case, I need to document that I'm drawing ASCII art and splitting a bill up. (Did I get that right?)

Comment: @HarrisonTran Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @Pimgd Again, for my trivial example, would renaming the function names to like runASCIISquareProgram() and runBillSplitterProgram() have been enough or should I also include comments?

Comment: @HarrisonTran In this case, you already have the problem description, so I'd just paste it right in! It's for school after all. Program description usually warrants a few lines of comments - this program is weird because it contains two programs. Normally you'd describe what the file contains at the top and you'd be done.

Answer (score 6):

@Pimgd has covered the readability of your code, so I just have a few points:

- You can't currently exit your program with the menu.  Although your menu contains '0. Exit', `getMenuSelection` won't return unless you pick PROGRAM_1 or PROGRAM_2.
- SQUARE_CHARATER should probably be SQUARE_CHARACTER
- Consider testing edge cases.  Your code rounds down the tip.  This means it's possible to achieve a 'you don't have to pay the bill' situation (which obviously wouldn't happen in real life):

  > ```
  > Enter the total of your bill (must be greater than 0): .03
  > Enter the number people that are splitting the bill (must be greater than 0): 7
  > With the tip percentage of 10.00%, each person pays 0.00 from a $0.03 bill.
  > ```
- Consider what happens if you type `one` for the number of people (or 0.1) etc.

Comment: Thank you! This is really interesting, I guess I need to be aware that any that reduces precision like std::setprecision(2) will introduce edge cases of rounding issues. Something I will definitely keep in mind forever.

Comment: Also I just entered .1 into the program and it produced a infinite loop, could you explain whats happening?

Comment: @HarrisonTran read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10349885/592182